# How to assign a destructor to a pointer?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a memory management library and need to call a destructor explicitly, in my design I have a pointer which points to the destuctor method of a object, I write code like this:

```
void (*p)() = foo.~Foo;
```

but I got

> error: cannot convert ‘Foo::~Foo’ from type ‘void (Foo::)() noexcept’
>   to type ‘void (*)()’

I tried some other format like `void (Foo:: (*p))() noexcept = foo.~Foo;` but failed.

So what is the right way to assignment a destructor to a pointer?

**Edit:**
at runtime my code do not know what a type it is in my heap, so I can't use foo.~Foo(). I need a generate pointer which fits for all destructors, is this possible?

Comment: A simple google search with source from [Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2016/09/25/to-store-a-destructor/) himself wouldnt help?

Comment: @reavenisadesk, what do you mean by not knowing the type ?? eg. do you mean a void* or it is known but abstracted like a template or it is inheritance  ? (the last case should just use virtual destructor)

Comment: @darune at first I decide to use void*, that's why I said I don't know the type (in runtime), but using the template wrapper you suggest do not have this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution: Use a template wrapper

Taking the address of the destructor isn't allowed.

However you can just make a very simple template function and use that instead:

```
template<class T>
void destruct(const T* x) {
    x->~T();
}
```

Now instead, just obtain the pointer from:

```
destruct<Foo>
```

You can use eg. `std::bind` (or a lambda) if you need to bind to an actual object:

```
std::bind(&destruct<Foo>, foo_ptr);
```

Please note that once it is *bound*, it cannot be converted to a raw function pointer.

Comment: _"at runtime my code do not know what a type it is in my heap"_

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the destructor is, of course, a member function so you'll need two pointers: one for the object and one for the offset of the member function (the destructor in this case).

To get the object's address is trivial, simply use [`std::addressof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof).

But to get to the destructor you'll need a wrapper function to invoke the destructor given the object's address because you can't take the address of a destructor.

So use something like [Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2016/09/25/to-store-a-destructor/) suggests (thanks to @LightnessRacesinOrbit's and @Croolman's comments):

```
[](const void* x) { static_cast<const Foo*>(x)->~Foo(); }
```

Comment: That is not "getting the destructor's 'offset' address". It is providing an unrelated lambda function that happens to contain a destructor call. Totally different thing. Good job, too, because you cannot take the address of a destructor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ahh, what was I thinking? Thanks, answer corrected.

Comment: Much better now :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you can't.  You are not allowed to take the address of a destructor per [[class.dtor]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor#2):

> A destructor is used to destroy objects of its class type. **The
>   address of a destructor shall not be taken.** A destructor can be
>   invoked for a `const`, `volatile` or `const volatile` object. `const`
>   and `volatile` semantics ([dcl.type.cv]) are not applied on an object
>   under destruction. They stop being in effect when the destructor for
>   the most derived object starts.

Answer (score 3):

> I need a generate pointer which fits for all destructors, is this possible?

No, it is not. Like it would not be with any other member function.

To call a function on an object, you need to know the type of that object.

And, since you cannot take the address of a destructor, you cannot even store/register one in a "database". However, as Paul showed, you can store a functor to do the job. It'll be a bit ugly to register these for each object in use, but that's what happens when you try to reinvent the type system!

I strongly advise moving away from type erasure (how about some nice inheritance instead?), and moving away from calling destructors yourself.